# Unable to populate option elements to select element using array.map()

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, jsx

I'm getting an array of vehicle makes from an api, and trying to map each item in the array to an option element within a select element:

```
  const Makes = () => {   
    return (
      <select aria-label="Select a make">
        {/* Populate with option elements based on the years state and its index */}
        <option value="">Select a make</option>
        {makes.map((make) => <option key={make.toString()} value={make}>test</option>)}
      </select>
    );
  };
```

`makes` is defined in the upper scope as an empty array, and I'm filling the array with a `fetchMakesByYear` function that looks like this:

```
  const fetchMakesByYear = async () => {
    const url = `https://www.fueleconomy.gov/ws/rest/vehicle/menu/make?year=${year}`;

    const headers = {
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/xml',
        Accept: 'application/xml',
      },
    };

    try {
      const data = await fetch(url, headers);
      const itemUnformatted = await data.text();
      const makesByYearUnformatted = convert.xml2js(itemUnformatted, { compact: true, spaces: 2 });
      const makesByYear = makesByYearUnformatted.menuItems.menuItem;

      for (let i = 0; i < makesByYear.length; i += 1) {
        makes.push(makesByYear[i].text._text);
      }
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchMakesByYear();
  });
```

Not sure why the options are not being populated. Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong here? Thanks.

Comment: are you setting state for `makes` after fetching and constructing it?

Comment: No. Whenever I try that, I get an error showing that I'm setting the state too many times causing an infinite loop. Any ideas on where I can add the make array to the state to prevent that error?

Comment: is it a functional component ? and you are you fetching the data on component mount?

Comment: Yup it's a functional component. Trying to use hooks instead of the lifecycle methods. I updated my code snippet all the way on the bottom to show that I'm calling the fetch function like so: `useEffect(() => {fetchMakesByYear();});`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use state to store the `makes` array and update it on fetch which will re render your component and `useEffect` to call your `fetchMakesByYear` on component mount.

Infinite render is because you have not passed dependency array in `useEffect`, so it calls it on every render.

```
const [makes,setMakes] = useState([]) // use state to hold your array

const fetchMakesByYear = useCallback(async () => { // use useCallback hook to wrap your function so that this function is not created on every render and hence doesn't call useEffect as we will be giving it as a dependency
    const url = `https://www.fueleconomy.gov/ws/rest/vehicle/menu/make?year=${year}`;

    const headers = {
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/xml',
        Accept: 'application/xml',
      },
    };

    try {
      const data = await fetch(url, headers);
      const itemUnformatted = await data.text();
      const makesByYearUnformatted = convert.xml2js(itemUnformatted, { compact: true, spaces: 2 });
      const makesByYear = makesByYearUnformatted.menuItems.menuItem;

      for (let i = 0; i < makesByYear.length; i += 1) {
        makes.push(makesByYear[i].text._text);
      }
      setMakes(makes) // set state to update your array in the state
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
},[]);

useEffect(()=>{
  fetchMakesByYear()
},[fetchMakesByYear]) // add dependency in useEffect here

return (
   {Makes()}
}
```